# Conditional CSS proprety set in computed object doesn't evaluate on the browser

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I am trying to make the `header` element's height size to change depending on a criteria. I set the desired heights in a `headerHeightClass` inside a `computed` object but it doesn't seem to work.

```html
<template>
  <header :class="['w-full', 'text-sm', 'headerHeightClass']">
    <div class="fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-16 bg-white">
            <!--Some irrelevant html code -->
    </div>
  </header>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "MainNav",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      isLoggedIn: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    headerHeightClass() {
      return {
        "h-16": !this.isLoggedIn,
        "h-32": this.isLoggedIn,
      };
    },
  },
  methods: {
    loginUser() {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I also tried:

```js
computed: {
    headerHeightClass() {
      return this.isLoggedIn? "h-32": "h-16",
    },
  },
```

The `headerHeightClass` appears as a simple string in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write it like this instead of using headerHeightClass as a string (remove '    ')

```js
<template>
  <header :class="['w-full', 'text-sm', headerHeightClass]">
    <div class="fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-16 bg-white">
            <!--Some irrelevant html code -->
    </div>
  </header>
</template>
```

This can also be written without using computed

```js
<template>
  <header :class="[
'w-full text-sm',
{
'h-16':!isLoggedIn,
'h-32':isLoggedIn,
}
]">
    <div class="fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-16 bg-white">
            <!--Some irrelevant html code -->
    </div>
  </header>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try like this (Just for a demo purpose I used Vue 2 version) **:**

```js
Vue.component('headerComponent', {
  props: ['msg'],
  template: '<p>{{ msg }}</p>'
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isLoggedIn: true
  }
});
```

```css
.w-full {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
}
.text-sm {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.h-16 {
  height: 16px;
}
.h-32 {
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <header-component
      msg="This is a header component"
      :class="['w-full text-sm', { 'h-16':!isLoggedIn, 'h-32':isLoggedIn }]">
  </header-component>
</div>
```